# Getting a Return Value from a Bean in Camel (Java)

Tags: java, variables, apache-camel

I am having a bit of trouble getting a return value from a bean in camel and using it in my route.

I have a route that looks like this:

```
from(file:test/?delete=true)
.unmarshal(jaxb)
.bean(testBean, "testMethod")
.to(direct:nextRoute);
```

The bean looks something like this:

```
public void testBean (PojoName pojoInstance){
  //do stuff 
  int i= 75; //a number I generate within the bean after I've started this method
}
```

I want to use the number I generate inside of my bean and in my route. Something like this:

```
from(file:test/?delete=true)
    .unmarshal(jaxb)
    .bean(testBean, "testMethod")
    .log(integer generated from testBean)
    .to(direct:nextRoute);
```

**What I tried:**

So, instead of returning void in my bean, I changed the return type to an int and returned the integer. Then, I was hoping to do something like this in my route:

```
.log("${body.intFromBean}")
```

My thinking is that once I return the value from a bean, it should store that value in the exchange body (at least that's what I'm getting from the Camel documentation). Then, I could access it in my route.

**The Problem:**
However, when I change the testBean return type to an int, I get the following errors:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Execution occurred during execution on the exchange 
Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: PojoName but has value: numberIGenerated of type java.lang.Integer
```

(Sorry I don't have the full stack trace. I'm using the s.o mobile app)

**My question:**
From reading some other s.o. submissions, I think I understand the problem. The message body is of one type and the return type is another. However, even when I tried using .

```
.convertTo(Integer.class)
```

before calling the bean, but that didn't work either. (Conceptually, that wouldn't work either because if I converted it to an int right after I unmarshalled it, I wouldn't be able to use the unmarshalled data. But I thought I'd try it anyway).

Can someone help me understand how I can properly return the integer and use it in my route?

I've read the documentation on bean binding and the exchange, and I thought I understood it well enough to do this. But I must be missing something.

Comment: Full stack trace, and full body of your bean (including testMethod implementation) etc. would be helpful, also full route would be helpful, where is testBean defined, etc. Also this looks rather iffy to me: ${body.intFromBean} from your log statement, but need more info...

Comment: Have you tried .log("${body}") instead of ${body.intFromBean}? camel stores the result AS your messages body.

Answer (score 5):

I think a simpler solution would be:

```java
public class TestBean {
     public int testMethod() {
        return 75;
    }
}
```

Whether you want the return result to be stored in a header or in the body should be up to the route definition.

As you read in the [Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html), the default behavior is to set the return value in the body:

```java
TestBean testBean = new TestBean();

from("file:test/?delete=true")
    .unmarshal(jaxb)
    .bean(testBean, "testMethod")
    .log("${body}")
    .to("direct:nextRoute");
```

And if you want it in a header:

```java
TestBean testBean = new TestBean();

from("file:test/?delete=true")
    .unmarshal(jaxb)
    .setHeader("MyMagicNumber", method(testBean, "testMethod"))
    .log("${header.MyMagicNumber}")
    .to("direct:nextRoute");
```

Be careful that if you use a Camel version older than 2.10, you will need to use the (now deprecated) "bean" method instead of the "method" method :-)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need to use it for you can either add it to the header or you can make it the body.

To add it to the header(key/value) do the following:

```
public class TestBean
{
     @Handler 
     public void testMethod
     (
        @Body Message inMessage,
        @Headers Map hdr,
        Exchange exch
     ) throws Exception
    {
        int i= 75;
        hdr.put("MyMagicNumber", i);

    }

}
```

Your "return" result is now stored in the header and you can read it from there in the steps that follow.

For the body do the following:

```
public class TestBean
{
     @Handler 
     public void testMethod
     (
        @Body Message inMessage,
        @Headers Map hdr,
        Exchange exch
     ) throws Exception
    {
        int i= 75;
        inMessage.setBody(i);

    }

}
```

The body of the message will now contain i.